# Magento 2: How to add a new customer attribute via Setup?

Tags: magento2, adminform, customer-attribute

I created this script to add a new customer attribute, but it's not saving on admin panel, why?

```
<?php

namespace Test\PhoneLogin\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    const CUSTOMER_PHONE_ATTRIBUTE =  'phone_number';

    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * InstallData constructor.
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @throws \Exception
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            self::CUSTOMER_PHONE_ATTRIBUTE,
            [
                'type'                  => 'varchar',
                'label'                 => 'Phone',
                'input'                 => 'text',
                'required'              => false,
                'visible'               => true,
                'user_defined'          => true,
                'position'              => 100,
                'system'                => 0,
                'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid'    => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                'is_searchable_in_grid' => true
            ]
        );
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, self::CUSTOMER_PHONE_ATTRIBUTE);
        $attribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit']

        );
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

**=> Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory**

instead of

**=> Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory**

Try this Code

```
<?php

namespace Test\PhoneLogin\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    const CUSTOMER_PHONE_ATTRIBUTE =  'phone_number';

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Phone',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 300,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script. This will help you.

```
<?php

namespace Test\PhoneLogin\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface

{

private $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'phone',
        'input' => 'text',
        'source' => '',
        'required' => true,
        'visible' => true,
        'position' => 333,
        'system' => false,
        'backend' => ''
    ]);


    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'phone_number')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'adminhtml_checkout',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]]);
    $attribute->save();
}

}
```